# Gradle plugin management

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, nexus

I'm trying to configure the plugin management for Gradle project to retrieve the plugin dependencies from Nexus.

I have the following line as the first block in the settings.gradle file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        if (project.hasProperty('kkvmvn')) {
            maven {
              url "${kkvmvn}"
            }
        } else {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'project' for repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.
```

Basically I need to access the command line parameter to set the Nexus URL. How do I do this in settings.gradle file? AFAIK it isn't possible to declare plugin repository in build.gradle file. Here is example how I retrieve other library dependencies in build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    // Java Version JDK 8
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    repositories {
        if (project.hasProperty('kkvmvn')) {
            maven {
              url "${kkvmvn}"
            }
        } else {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, gradle properties can be accessed in `settings.gradle` using the [Settings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html) object. So a conditional way to set plugin repositories would look something like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        if (settings.hasProperty('kkvmvn')) {
            maven {
              url settings.kkvmvn
            }
        } else {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
}
```